# How to configure SSL authentication

Tags: ssl, go, ssl-certificate

I have certificate.pem that I use to perform client authentication with a remote server. When I access the server, normally Chrome pops up, asks if I want to use that certificate, I say yes, then I'm authenticated. I'm trying to figure out why it's not sending the certificate with the dialer when I call it programmatically:

```
type DialerHelper func() (io.ReadWriter, error)
func DialIt(addr string, port uint16, config *tls.Config) (Dialer, error) {
    address := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", addr, port)
    return DialerHelper(func() (io.ReadWriter, error) {
        return tls.Dial("tcp", address, config)
    }), nil
}
caPool := x509.NewCertPool()
cert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("certificate.pem")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
ok := caPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(cert)
if !ok {
    panic(ok)
}

tlsconfig := &tls.Config{
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    RootCAs: caPool, }
tlsconfig.BuildNameToCertificate()
DialIt("some.address.com", 443, tlsconfig)
```

I keep getting an error from the server saying there is no client certificate supplied. Am I sending the SSL certificate correctly to the remote server? I'm not an expert with SSL.

Edit: this is the functionality I'm trying to replicate: `curl -k --cert /home/me/.ssh/certificate.pem`

Comment: You're replacing your RootCAs with your own certificate, which is definitely not what you want to do, and you shouldn't need to set InsecureSkipVerify. Have you tried just putting it in the `Certificates` field?

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. Thanks! I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: That's still not what a CA is for. Try putting putting the certificates in the Certificates field that the client will send to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is using a cert generated from your own Certificate Authority, then the following code will do the trick.

I've never tried Client Cert Authentication in an environment where the server cert is from a public CA, so I'm not sure how you'd achieve that. Perhaps just leaving out setting config.RootCAs.

```
func loadCertificates(caFileName, certFileName, keyFileName string) (tls.Certificate, *x509.CertPool, error) {

    myCert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certFileName, keyFileName)
    if err != nil {
        return tls.Certificate{}, nil, err
    }

    ca, err := ioutil.ReadFile(caFileName)
    if err != nil {
        return tls.Certificate{}, nil, err
    }

    certPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    if !certPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(ca) {
        return tls.Certificate{}, nil, errors.New("Failed appending certs")
    }

    return myCert, certPool, nil

}


func GetClientTlsConfiguration(caFileName, certFileName, keyFileName string) (*tls.Config, error) {
    config := &tls.Config{}
    myCert, certPool, err := loadCertificates(caFileName, certFileName, keyFileName)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    config.Certificates = make([]tls.Certificate, 1)
    config.Certificates[0] = myCert

    config.RootCAs = certPool
    config.ClientCAs = certPool

    return config, nil

}


tlsConfig, err := config.GetClientTlsConfiguration("ca.crt", "client.crt", "client.key")

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error loading tls config - %v", err)
}

client := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig}}

client.Get(.....)
```